# Trying to change the width of a button

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the width of the screen and then change the width of the button.  I'm using setWidth, and the width is not changing (I set it to a small numer, 30, so I could tell if the size change.
code
     mBut = (Button)findViewById( R.id.butRington);
             // this is not working, set the size small so i can really tell
             mBut.setWidth(30);
             mBut.setOnClickListener(this);

layouut

```
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:orientation="horizontal" > 

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/butVol"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:text="Volume"   
        android:textColor="#ff0000ff"

    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butRington"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:text="Rington"  
        android:textColor="#ff0000ff"

    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hanging layout_widht to wrap_content, I am able to change the width to what every size I need.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/butRington"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="R"
    android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
    android:textSize="24px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the LayoutParams of your button.

> mBut.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, xxxx));

where xxx is the height of your button. You can retrieve it by

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mBut.getLayoutParams();
params.height;
```

Check [this post](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the width of the screen:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x
```

Now you need to get your button, and then set the new width:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setWidth(width);
```